# How to make Toolbar in AppBarLayout to have transparent background

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I need to make transparent toolbar with buttons, but AppBarLayout adds white background to toolbar. Is there any way I can make toolbar which is in AppBarLayout to be transparent.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/activityBackgroundColor"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Overlay"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar.Translucent"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried entering background as "null" or I think the white background will be of coordinatorLayout. ?

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Are you sue it's not transparent? may be you're seeing the backgroud for the `CoordinatorLayout` since you used `android:background="?attr/activityBackgroundColor"`

Comment: Now I tried to move content higher by setting negative margin to my recyclerview `android:layout_marginTop="-56dp"` its working. Then my issue was not transparent background, but pushed down content. I am trying to use `?attr/actionBarSize` with negative sign as margin size. But can't find solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times we want the toolbar to be translucent because we want to show content behind it. The problem is that the colors of the content behind the toolbar can collide with the color of the toolbar elements/text (up/back arrow for example).

For that reason you'll see in a lot of implementations that the toolbar is actually not transparent but translucent with a gradient.

You can obtain this with the next code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent" />
```

background_toolbar_translucent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="@color/black_alpha_40"/>
```

colors.xml

```
<color name="black_alpha_40">#66000000</color>
```

You can play with different values on the gradient, what I've found is that for white elements, the black 40% works fine.

Another thing that you might want to do is to hide the title of the toolbar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And show the up affordance...

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```